# Control not entering if(isset()))

Tags: php, html

Below is the html code for my form and the php code which i am using to pass data to a class method.Now the problem that i have is that the control does not seem to enter the if loop which i concluded by testing as you can see."test0" gets printed but "test1" and other subsequent "tests" do not get printed.

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="job name">Job name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jobnm" value="<?php echo $_GET['jobnm'];?>" disabled>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="phone">Enter a phone number:</label><br><br>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="+91-1234567890" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required><br><br>
    <small>Format: 1234567890</small><br><br>
     </div>
     <label >Gender</label>
     <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="m">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="f">Female</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="o">Other</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="cvFile" required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Upload resume</label>
    </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" >Reset</button>
  </form>
```

```
<?php
require_once 'db-config.php';
require_once 'classCandi.php';
echo "test0";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "test1";
$jobID = $_GET['jobid'];
echo "test2";
$canName = $_POST['name'];
$canEmail = $_POST['mail'];
$canPhone = $_POST['phone'];
$canRadio = $_POST['optradio'];
echo "test3";
//Upload file
$fnm = "cv/";
$cvDst = $fnm . basename($_FILES["cvFile"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cvFile"]["tmp_name"],$cvDst);
echo "test4";
$obj = new Candi($conn);
$obj->storeInfo($jobID,$canName,$canEmail,$canPhone,$canRadio,$cvDst);
echo "test5";
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Submitted");';
echo '</script>';
echo "test6";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `control not entering if isset` ??

Comment: Try adding `name="submit"` to your submit button. In fact it might need to be an `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />` instead for this method to work

Comment: You might want to put the form `enctype` in quotes, as well. And normally the PHP code to process the form would come _before_ the form, so it doesn't get re-drawn when you submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code won't be true anytime! It's because you didn't understand how `$_POST` works.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

There's no input element in your frontend that has `name="submit"`. And to see, there's none of the inputs have `name` attribute at all.

Instead, the better way to do is, [**understand how this works**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and change your code so that, it includes:

- a `name` attribute for all the input and form elements.
- a check on the values and not `$_POST['submit']`

And finally...

- don't copy and paste without understanding the code.
- don't check on `$_POST['submit']` truthness.

Example, for `$canName = $_POST['name'];` to work, you need to have:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $something; ?>" />
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And have your attribute and values in quotes please:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
//      ^                   ^
```